# Calculating amount of propeller pitch for plane

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering

Me and a team are designing a plane and one of the goals is to have a variable pitch prop, however, I'm a bit lost as to how to do that. A lot of the factors depend on power output of the engine and prop length, but at this point I don't know where to start. I understand that as speed and altitude increases, pitch increases accordingly. The degree to which they change as altitude and velocity increases is what I need help with. (for a variable pitch propeller)

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of questions to clarify what you are looking for.  It is not clear what you are trying to control? Are you using a piston engine?
Are you trying to maximize airspeed?  Minimize fuel burn?
For a typical piston engine, the pilot can set the manifold pressure with a throttle control, and can set the RPM.  A mechanical control system then changes the prop pitch, to keep the desired RPM (on some very old aircraft the pilot actually sets the pitch).  The pilot uses a table to choose the settings, that is provided in the Pilot Operating Manual for the aircraft.  For example, here is part of the table from a Cessna 206, at 2000 ft  [image]
To use this table, first the pilot has to know the outside temperature (as an example assume 11C).  Then, for a given RPM (such as 2400) and a given Manifold Pressure (MP) such as 24" you can see the the engine generates 69% BPH (Brake Horse Power) and the airplane flies at 132 KTAS (Knots True Airspeed) and burns 15.6 GPH (gallons per hour).   If the pilot wants to save fuel, then he or she can reduce MP.  If the pilot wants to reduce noise, and engine wear, then it might be right to reduce RPM.  There are additional tables for different altitudes.  This table was probably generate based on flight test data.

Comment: I should have clarified, it will be a relatively small plane using electric motors to power the propellers. I don't know where to start to get data like the table that you provided me.